# Swing Update JList, error when the element of JList is selected

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to update the `JList` and refresh by click the `showAllInvoicesButton` and whenever I do that while one element in the `JList` is selected.

I get error message  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`.

But I never have problem when I click the button `selectbyMonthButton`. I could not figure it out exactly why?

I think it maybe when I click the `showAllInvoicesButton`, the `JList` value changed and it trigger the `setInvoiceSelection` method.

Below is part of the code I think that is related to this issue:

```
 LeftSide(InvoiceView enclosingView)throws DbException{
    this.enclosingView = enclosingView;
    mamaSplitPane = (BspSplitPane)enclosingView.getViewComponent();  
    JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("Select Invoice Number",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    headerLabel.setFont(Utility.FONT14B);
    mamaSplitPane.addLeftComponent(Utility.addEmptyBorder(
              Utility.wrapInJPanel(headerLabel),5,0,0,0));
    invoicesJList = new JList(Invoice.getInvoicesNumbersForLab().toArray());
    invoicesJList.addListSelectionListener(listSelectionListener);
    invoicesJList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jsp = new JScrollPane(invoicesJList);
    jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,220));
    Utility.addEmptyBorder(jsp, 5,4,20,4);
    mamaSplitPane.addLeftComponent(jsp);
    mamaSplitPane.addLeftComponent(makeButtonsPanel());
    setActionButtons();
  }
```

---

```
ActionListener buttonsActionListener = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
      LIMS.onlyGUI.setCursor(Utility.busyCursor);
  try {
    if (ev.getSource() == saveChangesButton) {

      setActionButtons();

    } else if (ev.getSource() == newInvoiceButton) {
        mamaSplitPane.removeComponentsFromRightStartingAtIndex(0);
        rightNewInv = new RightSideNewInvoice(enclosingView, enclosingView.leftSide);
        mamaSplitPane.addRightComponent(rightNewInv);
        mamaSplitPane.setRightPanelScrollAtZero();
        setActionButtons();
        mamaSplitPane.validate();

    }else if (ev.getSource() == cancelButton) {
      if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(cancelButton,
          "Are you sure you want to discard your changes?","Really Cancel?",
          JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
      {
        setInvoiceSelection();
      }
    }else if(ev.getSource() == deleteButton) {
      String[] message =  {"Are you sure you want to delete invoice the invoice? "};          
      if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(deleteButton, message,"Really Delete?",
          JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
      {


        setInvoiceSelection();
      }
    }else if(ev.getSource() == selectbyMonthButton){//added by YL
        String Month="";
        String Year="";
        Object message="Please type the Month and Year in format MM/YYYY";
        Object error_message1="Invalid format";
        Object error_message2="Empty Input";
        int m=1;
        int y=2014;
        boolean valid_input=true;
        String s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                selectbyMonthButton,
                            message,
                            "Input Month and Year",
                            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
                            );

        //If a string was returned, say so.
        if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0)) {
          StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(s,"/");



          try{
            if (st.hasMoreTokens())
                Month=st.nextToken();
            if (st.hasMoreTokens())
                Year=st.nextToken();
            m=Integer.parseInt(Month);
            y=Integer.parseInt(Year);

          }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              valid_input=false;
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(selectbyMonthButton,
                        error_message1,
                        "error",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
          }
        }else{
            valid_input=false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(selectbyMonthButton,
                    error_message2,
                    "error",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        //System.out.println(valid_input);
         if (valid_input) {
             InvoiceRecord invrec=new InvoiceRecord();
             ArrayList<String> InvoicNumberList=invrec.getInoiceNumbersbyMonth(invrec.readInvoicesByMonth(m,y));
             invoicesJList.setListData(InvoicNumberList.toArray());
             //System.out.println("select by month");
             mamaSplitPane.validate(); //must validate after change
             //mamaSplitPane.addLeftComponent(jsp);
         }

    }else if(ev.getSource() == showAllInvoicesButton){//added by YL
        mamaSplitPane.removeComponentsFromRightStartingAtIndex(0);
        invoicesJList.setListData(Invoice.getInvoicesNumbersForLab().toArray());
        mamaSplitPane.validate(); //must validate after change
        //mamaSplitPane.addLeftComponent(jsp);
    }
```

---

```
void setInvoiceSelection() throws DbException {
    mamaSplitPane.removeComponentsFromRightStartingAtIndex(0);
    int selectedIndex =  invoicesJList.getMaxSelectionIndex();
    //if (selectedIndex==-1)
    //     selectedIndex=1;
    //int selectedIndex =  invoicesJList.getMaxSelectionIndex();
    //System.out.println(selectedIndex);
      String invoiceNum = invoicesJList.getModel().getElementAt(selectedIndex).toString();
      currentInvoice = new Invoice(invoiceNum); // in model.projects.billing by YL
      enclosingView.invoiceTableRightSide = new RightSideInvoiceTable(enclosingView, mamaSplitPane, invoiceNum);
    //Utility.addEmptyBorder(invoiceTable,15,3,2,3);
    mamaSplitPane.addRightComponent(enclosingView.invoiceTableRightSide);
    mamaSplitPane.setRightPanelScrollAtZero();
    setActionButtons();
    mamaSplitPane.validate();
  }
```

Comment: Could you post your stack trace so that we can help you?

Comment: The code is horribly messy. But when you change the model of a `JList` (and thus, replace all its contents), then any previously selected element of the `JList` will have to become UN-selected. This causes a list selection event. And assuming that `setInvoiceSelection` is called due to a list selection event, you are not properly covering the case that no element is selected (that is, the `selectedIndex` is -1). You could insert a `if (selectedIndex==-1) return;` somewhere in this method, but we could only guess whether `mamaSplitPane.removeCom...whatever` should then still be called or not.

Comment: Thanks. I figure the same reason. But I don't know what do to fix this problem. What you suggest might works. I need to go back to office to try and see if it work. The code is from an existing project. I am working to add some features. Another thing that I am confused why when I click "selectbyMonthButton" while one element is selected, no error occurs. I mean it seems also changed the selection value from some thing to none.